# If both $\log(v1)$ and $\log(v2)$ are subharmonic functions, prove that $\log (v1+v2)$ is.

Tags: complex-analysis

Now I know that both $\log(v1)$ and $\log(v2)$ are subharmonic functions mapping from a complex domain to the real number.

Then how to prove that $\log (v1+v2)$ is also a subharmonic function?

Comment: Are you asking as a map from $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$???

Comment: Actually from a subset of the complex plane . Now I don't have an idea to make one.

Comment: (v1, v2) from the complex plane? are u sure?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't properly explained it. v1 and v2 are positive functions defined on a subset of C( the complex plane) and I know both of them are of C2, and both log v1 and log v2 are subharmonic. Now I was asked to prove that log (v1+v2) is also subharmonic.(Forgive me I don't know how to type formulae on the cellphone)